# How to redefine symbols inside my custom environment?

Tags: catcodes

I'm trying to create my own `foo` environment, which would be used like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
a -> b [
  c => d ]
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

I'm expecting it to render as:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& a \mapsto b \llbracket \\[1pt]
& \quad c \to d \rrbracket
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Is it at all possible? I need to tell TeX somehow that `->`, new line, leading spaces, `=>`, `[`, and some other symbols and their combinations must be "mapped" to something else.

Comment: To start with, do you guarantee that the `foo` will not be nested inside something else i.e. catcode changes are effective?

Comment: Yes, I will use `foo` only at the top level, never nesting into something else

Comment: See also http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#mspecdef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses the [`filecontentsdef`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/filecontentsdef) package to store the contents of the environment in a macro so that we can modify it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontentsdef}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % Provides \llbracket and \rrbracket.

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn {Nx}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {foo} {} {
    % Use filecontentsdef to store everything until "\endfilecontentsdefmacro" 
    % into a macro named "\l__envcontents_tmp_tl".
    \filecontentsdefmacro \l__envcontents_tmp_tl
} {
    \endfilecontentsdefmacro
    \str_set:NV \l__envcontents_tmp_tl \l__envcontents_tmp_tl
    
     % Drop the last newline (^^M) character
    \str_set:Nx \l__envcontents_tmp_tl {\str_range:Nnn \l__envcontents_tmp_tl {1} {-2}} 

    %%%% Do Replacements %%%%
    \tl_replace_all:Nxn \l__envcontents_tmp_tl {\tl_to_str:n{->}} {\mapsto}
    \tl_replace_all:Nxn \l__envcontents_tmp_tl {\tl_to_str:n{=>}} {\to}
    \tl_replace_all:Nxn \l__envcontents_tmp_tl {[} {\llbracket}
    \tl_replace_all:Nxn \l__envcontents_tmp_tl {]} {\rrbracket}

    % Replace "(newline)(space)(space)" with "\\[1pt] & \quad". This must be done after
    %  the replacement of "[" and "]", above, otherwise "[1pt]" gets replaced by "\llbracket 1pt \rrbracket".
    \tl_replace_all:Nxn \l__envcontents_tmp_tl {\cs_to_str:N \^^M \c_space_tl \c_space_tl} {\\[1pt] & \quad}  

    % Replace "(newline)" with "\\[1pt] &".
    % This must be done after the replacement of "(newline)(space)(space)"
    \tl_replace_all:Nxn \l__envcontents_tmp_tl {\cs_to_str:N \^^M} {\\[1pt] &}  

    % Wrap contents in "equation" and "split" environment.
    \tl_put_left:Nn \l__envcontents_tmp_tl {\begin{equation} \begin{split} &}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__envcontents_tmp_tl {\end{split} \end{equation}}

    % Typeset the result.
    \l__envcontents_tmp_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Example, using custom environment:
\begin{foo}
a -> b [
  c => d ]
\end{foo}

Example, entered explicitly:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& a \mapsto b \llbracket \\[1pt]
& \quad c \to d \rrbracket
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of Compiled Document]

You did not specify explicitly when you need a `\quad` exactly, so it's just a guess.

Strictly speaking, some `\tl_to_str:n` is not needed, but I put it there just in case.

There's some subtlety in the order of replacement needed; see the comments in the code.

Variables are named according to `expl3` naming convention. Edit if you prefer.

There's some additional subtlety with `filecontentsdef` if you want to use a literal tab character in the environment.

Comment: What does `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn {Nx}` do?

Comment: @PaulWintz It generates a command named `\tl_replace_all:Nxn` which does what it says. Refer to `texdoc interface3` for the documentation.