# How to make plain text be understood as a macro?

Tags: parsing

I'd like to create an environment, which will have its own parsing rules inside, for example:

```
\begin{foo}
a := 42;
c := a;
\end{foo}
```

Would be understood as:

```
a \mapsto 42 \\[2pt] c \mapsto a \\[2pt]
```

Here, `:=` is understood by TeX as `\mapsto` and `;` as `\\[2pt]`. Is it at all possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. (... I remember seeing a similar question somewhere else actually... but probably can't find it.)

Comment: Ah, here it is [catcodes - How to redefine symbols inside my custom environment? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660669/how-to-redefine-symbols-inside-my-custom-environment/660691#660691). Your own question actually...?

Comment: @user202729 sometimes I forget what I've already asked earlier :)

Comment: You can be inspired by http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#mspecdef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

The Lua function that does all of the work is activated when LaTeX enters the `foo` environment and is deactivated when LaTeX exits the `foo` environment. By “activation”, I mean assignment to LuaTeX’s `process_input_buffer` callback. While active, the Lua function acts as a preprocessor, checking and modifying the input stream *before* TeX starts its usual input processing.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function do_substitutions ( s )
  s = s:gsub ( ":=" , "\\mapsto " )
  s = s:gsub ( ";"  , "\\\\[2pt]" )
  return s 
end
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code
\newenvironment{foo}{%
  \directlua { luatexbase.add_to_callback (%
    "process_input_buffer" , do_substitutions , "do_subs" ) }}{%
  \directlua { luatexbase.remove_from_callback (%
    "process_input_buffer" , "do_subs" ) }}
  
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{foo}
\begin{array}{c}
a := 42;
c := a
\end{array}
\end{foo}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A token-cycle pseudo-environment `\foo...\endfoo` can accomplish this directly in (La)TeX.  I show not only the typeset result, but the detokenized tokens that result in the converted token list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle} 
\tokcycleenvironment\foo
{\ifx;##1\addcytoks{\\[2pt]}\else
 \ifx:##1 \tcpeek\z\ifx=\z\addcytoks{\mapsto}\tcpop\z\else
   \addcytoks{##1}\fi\else
 \addcytoks{##1}\fi\fi}
{\processtoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent$\foo
a := 42;
c := a;
\endfoo
%
\textrm{\detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]