# Avoid literal `\geq`, `\\`, and `\empty` in output when using `filecontentsdef` and `expl3`

Tags: expl3, cases

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660691/153678), I am trying to define a `newcases` environment that automatically expands "`if`" into "`, \quad & \text{if }`" and expands "`otherwise`" into "`, \quad & \text{otherwise}`".
My code and the output are included below. As you can see in the output, the result is incorrect with `\geq`, `\\`, and `\empty` rendered literally and `fl` inserted at each line break in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontentsdef}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn {Nx}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {newcases} {} {
    % Use filecontentsdef to store everything until "\endfilecontentsdefmacro" 
    % into a macro named "\l__envcontents_tmp_tl".
    \filecontentsdefmacro \l__envcontents_tmp_tl
} {
    \endfilecontentsdefmacro
    \str_set:NV \l__envcontents_tmp_tl \l__envcontents_tmp_tl

    \tl_replace_all:Nxn \l__envcontents_tmp_tl
      { \c_space_tl\tl_to_str:n{if} \c_space_tl} % Search
      {, \quad & \text{if~}}                     % Replace
    \tl_replace_all:Nxn \l__envcontents_tmp_tl 
      {\tl_to_str:n{otherwise}}       % Search
      {, \quad \text{otherwise}}      % Replace

    % Output the result.
    \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    \l__envcontents_tmp_tl
  \end{array}\right.
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Desired output:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    a, \quad & \text{if } a \geq 0, \\ 
    -a, \quad & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Actual output, using newcases environment:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{newcases}
    a if a \geq 0 \\ 
    -a otherwise.
  \end{newcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see the point in not specifying the & 's. Plus mathtools already provide cases* that plus the second vil in text mode

Comment: How many `if` will be used?

Comment: @daleif, I'd like to automatically include the comma before the `&`, so I'd like to not explicitly write `&`. The `cases*` environment looks useful, but I'd still like to define the environment I described, partially as a way of better understand `expl3` syntax.

Comment: @projetmbc, there may be multiple `if`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution without additional packages

Use a regex search and replace.

I'd not use `newcases` for the environment's name, because `mathtools` has a `\newcases` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__wintz_cases_tl

\NewDocumentEnvironment {autocases} {b}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__wintz_cases_tl { #1 }
    % Search any control sequences immediately followed by "if".
    % If there is, insert a space between so the subsequent regex works. 
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\c{.*}) if } { \1\ if } \l__wintz_cases_tl
    % Search and replace "<space>if<space>" with ", \quad & \text{if }"
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \s+if\s+ } { , \c{quad} \& \c{text}\{if\ \} } \l__wintz_cases_tl
    % Search and replace "otherwise" with ", \quad & \text{otherwise}"
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { otherwise } { , \c{quad} \& \c{text}\{otherwise\} } \l__wintz_cases_tl
    % Output the result.
    \begin{cases}
    \tl_use:N \l__wintz_cases_tl
    \end{cases}
  }{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Desired output:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    a, \quad & \text{if } a \geq 0, \\ 
    -a, \quad & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Actual output, using autocases environment:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{autocases}
    a if a \geq 0 \\ 
    -a otherwise.
  \end{autocases}
\end{equation}

Actual output, using autocases environment:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{autocases}
    \infty if a \geq 0 \\ 
    \oplus if a < -1 \\
    0 otherwise.
  \end{autocases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### With `filecontentsdef` (As in the original question)

***Caveat.*** You should also be aware that `autocases` (or whatever name you prefer) ***cannot*** be used in `amsmath` alignment displays. For an environment that can be used with `amsmath`alignment displays, use the approach described above.

You want to rescan the string you get.

Don't mix strings with token lists: they're different data types. You also forgot an `&` and want to use `cases`, not `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontentsdef}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \l__envcontents_tmp_str
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_replace_all:Nnn {Nx}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {autocases} {} {
    % Use filecontentsdef to store everything until "\endfilecontentsdefmacro" 
    % into a string named "\l__envcontents_tmp_str".
    \filecontentsdefmacro \l__envcontents_tmp_str
} {
    \endfilecontentsdefmacro

    \str_replace_all:Nxn \l__envcontents_tmp_str
      { \c_space_tl\tl_to_str:n{if} \c_space_tl} % search
      {, \quad & \text{if~}} % replace
    \str_replace_all:Nxn \l__envcontents_tmp_str
      {\tl_to_str:n{otherwise}} % search
      {, \quad & \text{otherwise}} % replace

    % Output the result.
    \begin{cases}
    \tl_rescan:nV {} \l__envcontents_tmp_str
    \end{cases}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Desired output:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    a, \quad & \textup{if } a \geq 0, \\ 
    -a, \quad & \textup{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Actual output, using autocases environment:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{autocases}
    a if a \geq 0 \\ 
    -a otherwise.
  \end{autocases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does using the name `l__envcontents_tmp_str` instead of `l__envcontents_tmp_tl` change the type? (I think not)  Or was `filecontentsdefmacro` outputting a string the whole time and the variable was just mislabeled?

Comment: @PaulWintz Both are actually macros, but sticking to the naming scheme is helpful in distinguishing between types. With `\filecontentsdefmacro` you get “verbatim”, that one might consider the same as a string.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. For the line `\c_space_tl\tl_to_str:n{if} \c_space_tl`, is that not still mixing strings (`l\tl_to_str:n{if}`) and token lists (`\c_space_tl`)?

Comment: @PaulWintz These are subtleties. However, you should read the final “Caveat” I added.

Comment: I'll keep the caveat in mind. What's the gist for why that doesn't work?

Comment: For this particular command, it's not a big deal since I don't put cases into aligned environments often, but it would be nice to know what aspect of this general approach prevents it from working in those aligned environments.

Comment: @PaulWintz You can't gather verbatim in the argument to a command. I'm going to add a version that's free from the problem.

Comment: if the code before the "if" is a macro without braces, then the output is not formatted right. For example, `\begin{autocases} \infty  if \gamma > 1. end{autocases}`
does not work right but `\begin{autocases} \infty{}  if \gamma > 1. \end{autocases}`. 
Is this something that can fixed by modifying the `autocases` environment?

Comment: @PaulWintz I added an initial search for “(control sequence) if” to add a space in the middle.